# Avoiding data leakage in preprocessing and handling unseen values in test data

Tags: scikit-learn, data-preprocessing, data-leakage

I've been reading up on [avoiding data leakage in the preprocessing step](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-without-data-leakage/) of a machine-learning/data-science pipeline, specifically that it is [wrong to apply preprocessing to both training and test data simultaneously](https://jfrog.com/community/data-science/be-careful-from-data-leakage/). Rather, a preprocessing model should be fitted to training data and then applied to test data, i.e. parameters of the preprocessing model (e.g. mean/variance) should not be estimated using the test data.

This makes sense as otherwise information from the test data could leak into the model fitted on the training data, and result in worse predictions on truly unseen test/validation data.

Whereas this seems fairly straight-forward for something like standardization (e.g. `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`), I'm wondering how to apply this when certain values of the predictors are unseen in the training data, but are present in the test data.

Specifically, consider the three following examples:

1. A categorical variable is present in the test dataset, which is not present in the training dataset, and `OrdinalEncoder` or `OneHotEncoder` are applied. (I note there are `handle_unknown` options in both encoders.)
2. An algorithm requires predictors to lie between 0 and 1, so `MinMaxScaler` is used. However, a value of the predictor in the test set lies outside the training data range.
3. We apply a log transform to a predictor variable, but a negative value appears in the test data, resulting in a domain error (i.e. a NaN value is produced).

In all three examples, we have made certain assumptions on the domain of the preprocessing model, based on the values in the training data, and when values in the test data lie outside of that domain, problems can occur. In contrast, applying `StandardScaler` wouldn't normally result in similar issues so long as the test variable is all numeric data.

Any advice on best practice for dealing with this problem is much appreciated. Thanks.